# Pathfinder Office - 0% base data coverage

Tags: post-processing

I am trying to post-process data collected with a Trimble Juno SB (sometimes hooked up to a ProXRT), in Pathfinder Office version 4.20.  I had no issues when I tested this in the US.  But now that I am in the field (Iceland), I keep getting " 0% total coverage.  No matching base data found."

The same files are working just fine on my colleague's computer.  Therefore, there must be something wrong with my configuration, but I can't figure it out - there are no obvious differences between my software setup and hers.  Any suggestions very welcome.

Here is the correction log.  Note that the Local Time for the base data spans 0 seconds, even though the reyk1740.15d file clearly contains data for the entire day.  My log files from data collected in the US, UK, and Ireland include a 24 hour span on this line.  What's wrong with my base data configuration, specific to my computer with data collected in Iceland??  Any suggestions very welcome!

I have the same problem regardless of which Icelandic base station I choose.

---

Searching for base files...

File [path redacted]\Iceland2\Base\SOPAC, Reykjavik, daily\reyk1740.15d.Z downloaded.
File [path redacted]\Iceland2\Base\SOPAC, Reykjavik, daily\auto1740.15n.Z downloaded.
Unable to transfer files.
Unable to download file from url ftp://garner.ucsd.edu/pub/nav/2015/174/auto1740.15n.g.
Successfully found or downloaded 2 of 3 files.
Search complete.

--------Base Data Details:--------------------

Using reference position from base provider:

Name: SOPAC, Reykjavik, daily
  Position: 64°08'19.61761"N,  21°57'19.74233"W,  93.05 m
Source: [path redacted]\Iceland2\Base\SOPAC, Reykjavik, daily
reyk1740.15d.Z
    Local time: **6/22/2015 23:59:46 to 6/22/2015 23:59:46**
    Position: 64°08'19.61688"N, 21°57'19.74045"W, 93.14 m, 0.06 m Antenna height
    Distance from base provider: 0.03m

--------Coverage Details:--------------------
Rover file: [file1]
  Local time: 6/23/2015 12:58:35 to 6/23/2015 14:39:46
  0% total coverage.  No matching base data found.

Rover file: [file2]
  Local time: 6/23/2015 14:40:30 to 6/23/2015 16:31:50
  0% total coverage.  No matching base data found.

Click Confirm to continue...

Answer (score 2):

Have you made sure to Update your base provider list?
You may have outdated download paths.

[image]

Comment: I had a similar problem.  This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be caused by the failure to download the auto1740.15n.g file (which I think may be the Nav data - almanac and emphemeris - for the GPS satellites.)  Where PFO looks for these files changed a couple of years ago - maybe when GPS + GLONASS became common.  If you haven't updated your base file list recently, you could try that.

If your colleague's computer gives the same error but post-processes OK, it's probably something else - you could compare the base file definitions (specifically the "Internet" properties, which define where PFO looks for the base files for a base).

Does your colleague have the same PFO version with the same updates applied?